# Do You Like Hats?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, site-promotion

Last year around Christmas time [arQAde](http://gaming.stackexchange.com) had an awesome promotion in which they awarded hats for gravatars for completing basic tasks around the site. If you don't remember it, here is a [link](http://stackexchange.com/promos/2/hat-dash) the promo from last year (and [another!](http://blog.gaming.stackexchange.com/2011/12/holiday-2011-hat-dash-the-hattening/)).

[image: hats]

This year, SE is planning to run it for *everyone* because we all love hats, right? right?

But to get this awesome hat promotion we have to **opt in**. That means acting on this meta post, whether that's voting it up, answering in the affirmative, positive comments and/or just directing positive energy this direction.

HOWEVER: this promotion is **optional** for sites, and/or individual users. If the users of this site *do not* want this in general feel free to voice that opinion. We can opt out of the promotion. Individual users will be able to opt out as well (they will be provided with an "I hate Hats" link to opt out).

Again, please let us know what you think as this is your site not ours.

---

Gardening & Landscaping has *opted in* for the hats promo.

Comment: Why not have flowers for us, instead of hats? I don't want a Skyrim or Assassin's creed hat on this site...

Comment: or carmen miranda style hats? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit_hat

Comment: @yoda the hats will be more generic than the gaming specific ones.

Comment: sure anything to get people to participate. XBox shows that people will do anything for little icons, why not hats?

Comment: Any final thoughts before I confirm our interest with SEI?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a great idea as long as the hats fit to the gardening topic.

Possible hats could be:

- a [fruit hat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fruit_hat) hat like Tea Drinker suggested
- or a [strawhat](http://us.cdn4.123rf.com/168nwm/billberryphotography/billberryphotography0801/billberryphotography080100044/2422606-straw-hat-with-a-bright-yellow-sunflower.jpg)
- or a [landscapers working helmet](http://www.lb3d.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/1-edited-preview-1024x1024.png)
- or [anything else](http://cdn04.cdnwp.thefrisky.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/19/hat-flower-pot.jpg) gardening and landscaping related.

Comment: too bad they couldn't do this ... but still one or two hats are sprouting here on gardening. too bad this is such a quiet time for us here.

Comment: At least the Copacabana hat for question score of 10 or more seems to look quite fruity :-) 
(Haven't seen him in colour yet, just greyed out)